# Chef server timezone configuration

Tags: chef-infra

Chef server management console displays node check-in time or uptime information in UTC timezone. Is there a way to modify the timezone to something else based on user preference?

Answer (score 0):

No, timezone selection is not currently a feature as far as I know. The Manage web interface is a closed-source project, so I can't say that with total certainty, however if you ask on the Chef mailing list I know that several members of its dev team will see your question/suggestion. The last check in time is stored internally as an epoch timestamp (seconds since Jan 1, 1970) so you can certainly convert it to any other timezone as needed in your own code. UTC is a fairly common standard for ops tools, so I suspect that should remain the default even if this is added.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! It would be nice to have this customization from UX perspective. Anyway, will post in chef mailing list as well.